# error with vector, unique_ptr, and push_back

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, unique-ptr

I am learning smart pointers, with the following example test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

struct abstractShape
{
    virtual void Print() const=0;
};

struct Square: public abstractShape
{
    void Print() const override{
        std::cout<<"Square\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<abstractShape>> shapes;
    shapes.push_back(new Square);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code has a compilation error "c++ -std=c++11 test.cpp":

```
smart_pointers_2.cpp:19:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
    shapes.push_back(new Square);
```

Could someone help explain the error to me? By the way, when I change `push_back` to `emplace_back`, the compiler only gives a warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`push_back` expects an `std::unique_ptr`, when passing raw pointer like `new Square`, which is considered as copy-initialization, the raw pointer needs to be converted to `std::unique_ptr` implicitly. The implicit conversion fails because `std::unique_ptr`'s conversion constructor from raw pointer is marked as `explicit`.

[`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) works because it forwards arguments to the constructor of `std::unique_ptr` and construct element in direct-initialization form, which considers `explicit` conversion constructors.

> The arguments args... are forwarded to the constructor as `std::forward<Args>(args)...`.

Comment: Thanks! How could I get rid of the warning `emplace_back`? I also tried `shapes.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Square>());`, and used c++14

Comment: @Memories you need a virtual-dtor in `abstractShape`, even if it is default. Add `virtual ~abstractShape() = default;` to that class. That should also allow C++14 make_unique semantics to wire up correctly as well. [See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/WYGxq991d).